# Derivative of a definite integral from a parameter

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, optimization

Is there any way to calculate $a$ to satisfy

$$\frac{\partial{F(a)}}{\partial{a}}=0,$$

where

$$F(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x,a)dx$$

$f$ can be any function but we know that the above integration cannot be expressed via an elementary function.

I am looking for a way which depends on $f$ or any of its derivatives however I dont want to solve such integral for all $a$.

Comment: Look at the third term in the first equation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign). This should help if you can solve for $a$s which make $\frac{\partial}{\partial a} f $ an odd function.

Comment: Thinking out loud: denote $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} = f_a$$ and we have $$F_a(a) = \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x,a)dx = \int_\mathbb{R} f_a(x,a) dx?$$

Comment: @gt6989b, as stochasticboy321 and you said, I can take the derivative inside the integration. Am I right?

Comment: @ar2015 if $f$ is nice, yes